# Помогите исправить ошибку pyrogram

Tags: python, pyrogram

Код:

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters
from pyrogram.errors import FloodWait
 
from pyrogram.types import ChatPermissions
 
import time
from time import sleep
import random
 
app = Client("my_account")
 
# Команда type
@app.on_message(filters.command("type", prefixes=".") & filters.me)
async def type(_, msg):
    orig_text = msg.text.split(".type ", maxsplit=1)[1]
    text = orig_text
    tbp = "" # to be printed
    typing_symbol = "▒"
 
    while(tbp != orig_text):
        try:
            await msg.edit(tbp + typing_symbol)
            sleep(0.05) # 50 ms
 
            tbp = tbp + text[0]
            text = text[1:]
 
            msg.edit(tbp)
            sleep(0.05)
 
        except FloodWait as e:
            sleep(e.x)
 
# Команда взлома пентагона
@app.on_message(filters.command("hack", prefixes=".") & filters.me)
async def hack(_, msg):
    perc = 0
 
    while(perc < 100):
        try:
            text = "‍ Взлом пентагона в процессе ..." + str(perc) + "%"
            await msg.edit(text)
 
            perc += random.randint(1, 3)
            sleep(0.1)
 
        except FloodWait as e:
            sleep(e.x)
 
    await msg.edit(" Пентагон успешно взломан!")
    sleep(3)
 
    await msg.edit(" Поиск секретных данных об НЛО ...")
    perc = 0
 
    while(perc < 100):
        try:
            text = " Поиск секретных данных об НЛО ..." + str(perc) + "%"
            await msg.edit(text)
 
            perc += random.randint(1, 5)
            sleep(0.15)
 
        except FloodWait as e:
            sleep(e.x)
 
    await msg.edit(" Найдены данные о существовании динозавров на земле!")
 
app.run()
```

Ошибка:

```
Pyrogram v1.1.13, Copyright (C) 2017-2021 Dan <https://github.com/delivrance>
Licensed under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License v3 or later (LGPLv3+)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 69, in <module>
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/run.py", line 61, in run
    self.start()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/sync.py", line 56, in async_to_sync_wrap
    return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/start.py", line 63, in start
    await self.send(raw.functions.updates.GetState())
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/advanced/send.py", line 77, in send
    r = await self.session.send(
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 425, in send
    return await self._send(data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 395, in _send
    RPCError.raise_it(result, type(data))
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/errors/rpc_error.py", line 78, in raise_it
    raise getattr(
pyrogram.errors.exceptions.unauthorized_401.SessionRevoked: [401 SESSION_REVOKED]: The authorization has been invalidated, because of the user t "updates.GetState")
Pyrogram v1.1.13, Copyright (C) 2017-2021 Dan <https://github.com/delivrance>
Licensed under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License v3 or later (LGPLv3+)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 69, in <module>
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/run.py", line 61, in run
    self.start()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/sync.py", line 56, in async_to_sync_wrap
    return loop.run_until_complete(coroutine)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/utilities/start.py", line 63, in start
    await self.send(raw.functions.updates.GetState())
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/methods/advanced/send.py", line 77, in send
    r = await self.session.send(
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 425, in send
    return await self._send(data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/session/session.py", line 395, in _send
    RPCError.raise_it(result, type(data))
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyrogram/errors/rpc_error.py", line 78, in raise_it
    raise getattr(
pyrogram.errors.exceptions.unauthorized_401.SessionRevoked: [401 SESSION_REVOKED]: The authorization has been invalidated, because of the user terminating all sessions (caused by "updates.GetState")
```

Comment: Код и ошибка соединились а я не заметил. Извиняюсь.

Comment: Под текстом есть кнопка "править" и можно всегда отредактировать текст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

И так. Я решил проблему в тот же день но забыл оставить тут ответ. Нужно было всего лишь удалить файл который создался при первой авторизации.